# Can developers perform optimizations in apk creation using dx tool?

Tags: android, developer-tools

dx tool is present in android build tools, and developers need not specifically invoke this tool during creation of **.dex/.apk.**
Can a developer perform any further optimizations in the **.dex/.apk** creation process to optimize the output **.dex/.apk** file for better performance on device?

Comment: The Dalvik bytecode is compiled to native, so most speed/space tradeoffs will ultimately have little to no effect. Did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: @fadden The dx.bat file has several options like --no-optimize, no-optimize-list etc that seem to suggest some optimizations can be performed during dx usage.
I am interested in finding out if there are any optimizations developers usually perform for better performance.

Comment: All dx optimizations should be enabled by default.